# google maps compute area overlaycomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the overlaycomplete callback to get area calculations of shapes as they are drawn, however it seems impossible to get any path information from the overlaycomplete callback? i've tried using getPaths()  and it just keeps saying getPaths is not a function...  Tried to find a way to get or build a MVCArray of the shape drawn, also not working...I am using the Drawing Controls library that has the Circle, Rectangle, and Polygon options enabled...  or is there another method i can use that would let me get the area of all shapes drawn on the map?

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map;
var allCircles=new Array();
var allRectangles=new Array();

var allPolygons=new Array();

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 13    
    });

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: ['circle','polygon','rectangle']
        },
        circleOptions: {
            fillColor: '#888888',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        },
        rectangleOptions: {
            fillColor: '#888888',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#888888',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        }
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(thisShape) {
        if (thisShape.type == 'circle') {
            allCircles.push(thisShape.getPaths());
        }else if(thisShape.type == 'rectangle'){
            allRectangles.push(thisShape.getPaths());
        }else if(thisShape.type == 'polygon'){
            allPolygons.push(thisShape.getPaths());
        }
    });

}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]&libraries=drawing,geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. `getPaths()` is available if the shape type is `polygon`. The reason why you're getting the error is because `thisShape` (*from your code sample*) return 2 objects such as `type` and `overlay`. To properly use `getPaths()`, you must first target overlay since the paths can be found inside that object. the code must look something like this:

```
thisShape.overlay.getPaths();
```

However, for shapes such as circle and rectangle, `getPath()` would not work since you did not plot the points of the shape. It is stated in the [Circles documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circles) itself

> Unlike a Polygon, you do not define paths for a Circle. Instead, a circle has two additional properties which define its shape
>
> - `center` specifies the google.maps.LatLng of the center of the circle.
> - `radius` specifies the radius of the circle, in meters.

and in the [Rectangles Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#rectangles)

> Unlike a Polygon, you do not define paths for a Rectangle. Instead, a rectangle has a `bounds` property which defines its shape by specifying a google.maps.LatLngBounds for the rectangle.

To access these information from the return after `overlaycomplete` callback, using your codes as a sample, here's how:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(thisShape) {
```

For circles, you can only use `getCenter()` and `getRadius()`.

```
  if (thisShape.type == 'circle') {
    console.log("center: " + thisShape.overlay.getCenter());
    console.log("radius: " + thisShape.overlay.getRadius());
```

and for the rectangle, `getBounds()`. (*In any case that you are not aware of how to extract the data inside this, you may use `getNorthEast()` and `getSouthWest()`.*)

```
  }else if(thisShape.type == 'rectangle'){
    bounds = thisShape.overlay.getBounds();
    console.log("north east: " + bounds.getNorthEast());
    console.log("south west: " + bounds.getSouthWest());
```

Now for the last part, to access the `latLngs` after finishing the shape, simply use `getPaths()`. Then to get the points from inside this object, I simply targeted the where the array of `latLngs` can be found:

```
  }else if(thisShape.type == 'polygon'){
    console.log("lat lngs: " + thisShape.overlay.getPaths());
    console.log(thisShape.overlay.getPaths().b[0].b);
  }
});
```

Although these information does not exactly give you the area of the shape, it gives enough information to recreate them on the same location in the map.

You may check this [working sample](http://jsbin.com/peyizod/edit?js,console,output). Just try adding shapes and see the returns in the console.

Hope this helped!!